# jQuery Hover Problems in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, internet-explorer-7

I have an image that, when hovered over, should display another image with 4 absolutely positioned links. This code works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and all versions of IE except IE7. Any help with IE 7?

Here's the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/derekbrown/2qVK2/21/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add position: relative to .info-box, and I don't see an element with the id of hot-buy-collapse, so when I test that in IE7, the space for that image appears to still be taken?

Comment: Sorry: hot-buy-collapse is an image to the left of the expansion that gets collapsed as it expands. Also, #hot-buy-rollover already has position:relative on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the initial image is still taking up space on the page despite setting opacity to 0. This can be seen by editing the line which sets the image to opacity 0 to 1; when hovered both images will be shown side by side.

You need to somehow remove the initial image from the document flow on hover. This is normally done by setting the display property to none. I've updated the jsfiddle to show this in action but the animation is totally smooth. Ill edit my answer I can improve on its implementation

http://jsfiddle.net/2qVK2/19/

EDIT: This is better, sets the width, animation is much smoother.

http://jsfiddle.net/2qVK2/20/

Comment: I like this animation much better, but it still isn't working properly in IE7. I believe it to be something with the collapsing image. I've updated the JSFiddle to include the full code here: [http://jsfiddle.net/derekbrown/2qVK2/21/](http://jsfiddle.net/derekbrown/2qVK2/21/)